# Elements of web design

Tags: web-development, website-design

What are some core elements of great web design?

Things like speed, layout, etc... Can we determine a something from the community for what we have all tried and works?

Comment: ............ Care to comment on that downvote?

Comment: I didn't downvote but this question sounds incredibly vague to me...

Comment: Well there's lists all over the place of elements of web design, regular design, what abstractions make things "good". http://www.everybodygoto.com/2007/04/12/10-elements-of-web-design-today/

Of course there is the element of expairmentation leading to new things, but I'm asking about previously attempted things that have worked. For example, what may make a good UI is following fitt's law, high-contrast colours, etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your best bet is reading the books on [Jeff Atwood's reading list](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2004/02/recommended-reading-for-developers.html) that deal with web design.

Beyond that to me it is all about:

1. Elegant layouts
2. Speed
3. Low number of bugs
4. Elegant layouts
5. Elegant layouts
6. Elegant layouts

Answer (score 2):

1. Valid markup - so you know it works in all browser past, present, and future (bugs excluded of course)
2. Lean code - less code means faster page loading and usually faster rendering
3. Usability - it may look pretty but if I can't figure out how it works I'm leaving
4. Accessibility - disabled people use the web, too
5. Flexible - it works on screens and devices large and small
6. No unnecessary content or gimmicks